# Запрет сохранения страницы в кеш

Tags: javascript, php

Каким скриптом запретить странице сохраняться в кеш?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из способов - рандомный параметр в адресной строке, например, "`http://myssite.com/index.php?r=123412341234`", здесь параметр r не несет смысловой нагрузки, однако за счет того, что при каждой загрузке страницы он разный, браузеры считают адрес уникальным и каждый раз загружают страницу.

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь соответствующими HTTP-заголовками.

```
<?php 
function ae_nocache() 
{
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
}
?>
```

Или попробуйте добавить на страницу теги:

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Comment: А с html никак?

Comment: Вот это как раз для html! Но тут лучше выбрать или cahce-control или pragma. Одно из двух.

    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос стоит: "Не попадать в кеш", то ответ такой:
страница все равно будет в кеше. Все всегда сохраняется в кеш в браузере, заголовки отвечают только за то, как долго страницы там находится. Так что физически любой файл всегда попадает в кеш.

А если вопрос "Всегда запрашивать новую версию с сервера", то поможет get параметр типа `http://example.com/file.xxx?time`. Где time - таймстемп времени в миллисекундах, например. Документ c get параметром всегда считается сгенеренный динамически, поэтому если параметр меняется, то браузер думает что это новый документ и всегда его грузит заново. Но эту логику могут ломать прокси, которые могут отбрасывать get параметры, поэтому лучше делать что-то типа ЧПУ: `http://example.com/file/time/`, где time опять же время в миллисекундах.